# Is there a way to know which Android API version is my flutter app using?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I need to know which Android API version is my Flutter app using, I need to change it too if that's like the 29 API to support Android 6.0 using API 26 I guess.

Comment: Do you mean changing target and compile sdk version here? `./android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: Yes, thanks! So, I have minSdkVersion as 21, and targetSdkVersion as 27, so, as minimum is 21, it allows me to work with API level 23 (Android 6.0), right? or Should I change the target sdk version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open your android `build.gradle` (Module:app)  and there you can see :

> minSdkVersion
>
> targetSdkVersion
>
> compileSdkVersion etc.

Comment: I have minSdkVersion as 21.
compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion as 27. So, that means that I will be able to work with Android 6.0, right? I mean because minSdkVersion is 21, and Android 6.0 is API 23 I guess, am I okay?

Comment: @JosephArriaza sure. Android 6.0 is API level 23, so you are in.
 If you want to support the latest you have to upgrade compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion.

Comment: So, that means that each time that a new Android version is released, I have to update compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion, right?

Comment: @JosephArriaza yup, you got it right. Update to the latest, and also update the libraries as follows. Also if you found the answers useful, you can mark it at the main answer.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) package:

```dart
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
final androidInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
return androidInfo.version.sdkInt;
```

Comment: this should be the right answer to knowing api version on runtime

Answer (score 3):

You can check the SDK information in the file: `<your app root>\android\app\build.gradle`. The SDK version information can be find in `defaultConfig`. Please check it below:

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "some.some.some"
        minSdkVersion 16 <--- here
        targetSdkVersion 28 <--- here
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

run in the terminal "flutter doctor" and you can see the current SDK version.